# Array difference associative array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, array-difference

```
$invitedfrnds0 = Array 
            ( [0] => Array 
                ( 
                    [fb_user_id] => 100000058716604 
                    [accept_status] => 0 
                ) 
             [1] => Array 
                ( 
                    [fb_user_id] => 100000063917115 
                    [accept_status] => 0 
                ) 
            [2] => Array 
                ( 
                    [fb_user_id] => 100000261361844 
                    [accept_status] => 0 
                ) 

            [3] => Array 
                ( 
                    [fb_user_id] => 100005502043347 
                    [accept_status] => 0 
                ) 

            ) 

$invitedfrnds2 =    Array 
                ( 
                    [0] => Array 
                        ( 
                            [fb_user_id] => 100005502043347 
                            [accept_status] => 2 
                        ) 
                )
```

here i have two array `$invitedfrnds0` and `$invitedfrnds2`, there is some matching `fb_user_id` in these two arrays, if any matching is found i need to delete the matching record form first array. After that i need to merge these two arrays

result array will look like this way.

```
$resultarray = Array 
                ( [0] => Array 
                    ( 
                        [fb_user_id] => 100000058716604 
                        [accept_status] => 0 
                    ) 
                 [1] => Array 
                    ( 
                        [fb_user_id] => 100000063917115 
                        [accept_status] => 0 
                    ) 
                [2] => Array 
                    ( 
                        [fb_user_id] => 100000261361844 
                        [accept_status] => 0 
                    ) 

                [3] => Array 
                    ( 
                        [fb_user_id] => 100005502043347 
                            [accept_status] => 2 
                    ) 

                )
```

I have searched a lot for this, tried some

```
 $resultarray = array_diff($invitedfrnds0,$invitedfrnds2); 
 $resultarray = array_map('array_diff_assoc', $invitedfrnds0, $invitedfrnds2);
```

But not getting it right, please help me to solve this issue, thanks

Comment: Please put in just some basic effort at formatting your question and your text.

Comment: php's array functions are handy,b ut they're not swiss army knives. Sometimes you just have to get dirty and write loops to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `array_merge_recursive()`, not `array_diff()`:

```
array_merge_recursive($invitedfrnds2, $invitedfrnds0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [array_udiff](http://php.net/array_udiff) you could achieve this.

```
$invitedfrnds0 = array(
    array('fb_user_id' => 100000058716604, 'accept_status' => 0),
    array('fb_user_id' => 100000063917115, 'accept_status' => 0),
    array('fb_user_id' => 100000261361844, 'accept_status' => 0),
    array('fb_user_id' => 100005502043347, 'accept_status' => 0),
);

$invitedfrnds2 = array(
    array('fb_user_id' => 100005502043347, 'accept_status' => 2),
);


// remove all matched values.
$result = array_udiff($invitedfrnds0, $invitedfrnds2, function($a, $b)
    {
    return $a['fb_user_id'] - $b['fb_user_id'];
    });

// add values from the second array.
$result = array_merge($result, $invitedfrnds2);
var_dump($result);
```